# How to set dropdown value placed inside <tr> tag using its value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a dropdown list inside  tag

```
 <td id="tdStatus" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

Now I need to select a particular item based on value returned from database.

I stored the value in variable `ddl`.

How can I identify this dropdown and select value using jQuery..?

I used the following code also, but not working..

```
$('#dropdownID').val("Value to be selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this one:

```
$('#<%=ddlStatus.ClientID%>').val("Value to be selected");
```

The id of the dropdown in the markup that is generated by asp.net's view engine differs from the id you define in your markup, in order to access your server side control in your code behind class.

Comment: Check your code behind file name and Inherits property on the @Page directive.

Answer (score 0):

You are having ID attribute for td element. you can use:

```
$('#tdStatus select').val('set new val');
```